# When I run batch file, I get the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to patch something and to fix the patch we usually archive the old file on windows and replace it with the file with a patch.

I am using copy statement to do this: `copy /y file.template "..\..\server\Process\"`

When the file gets to this point it is outputting either access denied, or when I run it as admin I get: the system cannot find the file specified.

I am not sure what the problem is? I might be running the batch file wrong or maybe it is the statement.

Operating system: windows 8
Thanks

I have tried running the file as admin. I have taken the copy line and ran it separately, I keep getting access denied or the system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Clearly either file.template or the path ..\..\server\Process\ does not exist.  Run it from the command line rather than the batch file as a debug investigation.  If it works, then the working directory when you run the batch file is wrong.  Executing a command from a shell is not programming or software development, so off topic.  This is just operating a computer.

Comment: When you run a script as administrator, the command prompt opens in `C:\Windows\System32` instead of where the script is located. Stick a `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the top of your script to make sure that you are where you think you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran powershell as admin and cd into that folder then just ran the batch file like below and it worked.

```
cd batchFile/patch
./file.bat
```

I couldn't figure out how to run it on command prompt but I've found something [here](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)